# Optimizar código al lanzar varias veces la misma excepción en un mismo método

Tags: java, excepciones

Estoy creando una implementando de un grafo genérico en Java, para hacer un proyecto mas adelante utilizando esta estructura de datos. Pero al avanzar e ir creando los métodos del grafo **(Estoy intentando hacer la implementacion con lista de adyacencia)**, me he encontrado con que en un mismo método o función tengo que **lanzar varias veces la misma Excepción**, la cual es **NullPointerException**, pero en diferentes situaciones, si se llegan a presentar, claro esta.

Entonces mi pregunta es: ¿Puedo optimizar todos todos esos **else** que, me lanzan **NullPointerException**, en uno solo? ya que el código como lo muestro no se ve, para mi, muy presentable y, la verdad, utilizar Excepciones no es que sea mi punto fuerte en programación.

```
 @Override
public void addEdge(Vertex<K, V> source, Vertex<K, V> destination, double weight) throws KeyNotFoundException {
    if (source != null){
        if (destination != null){

            if (source.getKey() != null){
                if (destination.getKey() != null){

                    if (isInGraph(source.getKey())){
                        if (isInGraph(destination.getKey())){

                            Edge<K,V> edge = new Edge<>(source, destination, weight);
                            this.adjacencyList.get(source.getKey()).add(edge);

                            if (!isDirected){
                                Edge<K,V> edge2 = new Edge<>(destination, source, weight);
                                this.adjacencyList.get(destination.getKey()).add(edge2);
                            }
                            this.numberOfEdges++;

                        }else {
                            throw new KeyNotFoundException("El parametro key del objeto Destination no se encontro.");
                        }
                    }else {
                        throw new KeyNotFoundException("El parametro key del objeto Source no se encontro.");
                    }

                }else {
                    throw new NullPointerException("El objeto Destination, en su parametro key, es nulo!");
                }
            }else {
                throw new NullPointerException("El objeto Source, en su parametro key, es nulo!");
            }

        }else {
            throw new NullPointerException("El objeto Destination es nulo!");
        }
    }else {
        throw new NullPointerException("El objeto Source es nulo!");
    }
}
```

Por si algo:

- El objeto lanzado **KeyNotFoundException** es una excepción propia.
- El objeto llamado **adjacencyList** es un HashTable que tiene como key un parametro del objeto vertex, y como value una List de objetos Edge
- Si se preguntan porque soy tan especifico en remarcar que objeto es el que esta nulo, es para poder mostrarselo tambien al usuario, y para guiarme mas facilmente, mas adelante, cuando empiece con el proyecto que usara esta implmentacion de Grafo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aquí hay varias cosas que se pueden mejorar:

1. Se me hace un poco raro que lances `NullPointerException`, se suele usar como convención `IllegalArgumentException` cuando el parámetro de un método no sea válido por la razón que sea (nulo, rango inválido, etc.) Mejor aún, si usas excepciones personalizadas para tu aplicación, por si quieres que se fuerce la captura de excepción, ya que tanto `NullPointerException` como `IllegalArgumentException`  son excepciones de runtime y no estás obligado a capturarlas.
2. Las comprobaciones de parámetros que haces en los dos primeros ifs encadenados simplemente verifican el valor de entrada antes de hacerles ninguna transformación, y en caso de que no sean correctos no vas a salir inmediatamente del método tirando una excepción, por lo que puedes hacer algo así:

```
/**
 * Valida si un valor es nulo y en caso de que lo sea lanza una excepción.
 * @param value Valor a comprobar
 * @param name Nombre del parámetro
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException En caso de que el valor sea nulo.
 */
private void validarNulo(Object value, String name) throws IllegalArgumentException {
  if (value == null) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(name + " es nulo");
  }
}

/**
 * Valida si un vértice está en el grafo y en caso de estarlo lanza una excepción.
 * @param vertex Vértice a comprobar
 * @param name Nombre del parámetro
 * @throws KeyNotFoundException En caso de que el vértice esté en el grafo.
 */
private void validarEstaEnGrafo(Vertex<K, V> vertex, String name) throws KeyNotFoundException{
  if (isInGraph(vertex.getKey())){
    throw new KeyNotFoundException("El parametro key del objeto " + name " + no se encontró.");
  } 
}

@Override
public void addEdge(Vertex<K, V> source, Vertex<K, V> destination, double weight) throws KeyNotFoundException, IllegalArgumentException {

  // Primero valido todo lo necesario para que funcione mi método
  // Tiene pinta que las validaciones se van a hacer muchas veces, así que creo un par de métodos privado para no repetir tanto código.

  validarNulo(source, "source");
  validarNulo(destination, "destination");

  validarEstaEnGrafo(source, "source");
  validarEstaEnGrafo(destination, "destination");


  // A partir de aquí puedo asumir que todos los parámetros de entrada son válidos, sigo con el resto del método sin incrementar la complejidad

  Edge<K,V> edge = new Edge<>(source, destination, weight);
  this.adjacencyList.get(source.getKey()).add(edge);
  if (!isDirected){
    Edge<K,V> edge2 = new Edge<>(destination, source, weight);
    this.adjacencyList.get(destination.getKey()).add(edge2);
  }
  this.numberOfEdges++;
}
```

De esta manera no incrementas la complejidad ciclomática de tu método innecesariamente (¿qué pasaría si tuvieses 7 parámetros?) y la parte principal de tu método estaría al primer nivel de indentación facilitando su lectura.